# What is a good use case for tr1::result_of?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, tr1, use-case

I hear that tr1::result_of gets used frequently inside of Boost... I'm wondering if there are any good (simple) use cases for tr1::result_of I can use at home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A description of result_of is given at [open_std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1454.html).  Microsoft has a quick example of a [unit test wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982028.aspx) that uses result_of.

Comment: From the Microsoft example, it seems that the advantage of result_of is that it adds a trait describing the returned type. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

There are no simple cases. However, it's used in `BOOST_AUTO`, which can be used, e.g., in

```
BOOST_AUTO(x, make_pair(a, b));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's useful when doing meta-programming. The only time I used it was in a wrapper function. If result_of<T>::type was void, the wrapper returned nothing. Otherwise it returns the whatever the wrapped function returns.

Comment: just so you know, c++ allows returning void in some cases. for example:
"template<class T> T func() { return T(); }" is valid even when T is void.